# what minimum role and access rights required for sitecore login

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

I have created new user in sitecore and also created new role with read access for entire content tree But I am not able to login into CMS. I want to know what is the minimum requirement for login user in Access viewer and security editor? If I make it that user as admin then I am able to login.

Answer (score 4):

To enable login, it's the `Sitecore Client Users` role.

> Gives the user minimal access to Sitecore. With this role, the user
>   can log in to the Sitecore Desktop, but will not have access to any
>   applications.
>
> All of the other Sitecore client roles are members of the Sitecore
>   Client Users role, which means that users in any Sitecore client role
>   are automatically members of the Sitecore Client Users role.

For security I think you will need `Sitecore Client Securing`.

> Gives the user access rights to security features in the Content
>   Editor and other relevant applications.
>
> This role is intended for users who need to maintain users and access
>   rights.

All info on the roles can be found here: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/the_security_roles

Comment: Thanks... Really helpful